# How can I use Base map from GIBS in Arcgis android Sdk

Tags: android, arcgis, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-android-api

I want to use latest imagery from [NSA GIBS](https://wiki.earthdata.nasa.gov/display/GIBS/) in arcgis android sdk is it Possible?
Also can I download tiles from above service to cache/offline map?

I have tried:
[WMSLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/latest/api-reference/reference/com/esri/arcgisruntime/layers/WmsLayer.html) class from arcgis android
and
[WebTiledLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/latest/api-reference/reference/com/esri/arcgisruntime/layers/WebTiledLayer.html)

Following code I used For WebTiledLayer

```
    mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);


    String templateUri = "https://gibs.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts/epsg3857/best/MODIS_Terra_Aerosol/default/2014-04-09/GoogleMapsCompatible_Level6/{level}/{row}/{col}.png";

    // webtile layer
    final WebTiledLayer webTiledLayer = new WebTiledLayer(templateUri);
    webTiledLayer.loadAsync();
    webTiledLayer.addDoneLoadingListener(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (webTiledLayer.getLoadStatus() == LoadStatus.LOADED) {
                // use webtile layer as Basemap

                final ArcGISMap map = new ArcGISMap(new Basemap(webTiledLayer));

                mMapView.setMap(map);

                // custom attributes
            }else {
                webTiledLayer.getLoadError().printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

And result was an empty map

Comment: Good work with the edit! There are, however, some close-votes on your question. (You can't see it, but I can, due to my rep level here.) You may want to edit more - tell us what happened when you tried these things. If you have code snippets that show how WMSLayer and WebTiledLayer didn't work for you, include them. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tested your code and it seems to work just fine. Have you requested internet permissions in your manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Try dropping your code in the onCreate of [this sample](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-android/tree/master/java/display-map)--it'll work.